# Backwards compatibility of vector (de)serialization with Boost.serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

*Sorry for cross posting. After posting to the mailing list boost-users and one week without any responses I am inclined to post the issue at stackoverflow.
Original Post, slightly re-edited:*

Hi list,

I am migrating from Boost v1.35 to a new version. I have, however, some 
legacy serialized strings that I want to be readable by the new version.

After some testing I found that apparently the newer version (in this 
case 1.40 but also later) cannot correctly deserialize std::vector instances from 1.35 
generated strings. Can anyone give my a pointer as to what may be the 
problem here?

Thanks a lot!

Ewald

==Details==

I use text archives, and gcc version 4.4.1 (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9)

The test vector is a structure with 2 items, the long integers 1 and 2.

Archive string for respective lib versions:

1.35: `archive: 22 serialization::archive 4 2 1 2`
1.40: `archive: 22 serialization::archive 5 2 0 1 2`

Now:

```
// includes
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

std::vector<long> testvector;
std::string val = "22 serialization::archive 4 2 1 2"; // v1.35 archive
{
std::stringstream ss(std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out);
ss << val << std::endl;
boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(testvector);
}
```

Result when executing with lib v1.40: testvector contains two elements, 
`{2, 2}` -- instead of `{1, 2}`

Note: s11n and de-s11n with the same lib version works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

There is a file `boost/serialization/vector_135.hpp` at least in Boost 1.48 with this comment:

> vector_135.hpp: serialization for stl vector templates for compatibility  with release 1.35, which had a bug

I presume you could include it instead of `boost/serialization/vector.hpp`.  The downside, of course, is that newly serialized vectors will be in that buggy format too in that case.

**EDIT:**

Brief study of the code suggests if the file is used, `load()` will be able to deserialize both formats, but `save()` will serialize in the new format.  So, the only downside seems to be ugly include name then.

Comment: Just tried it with Boost 1.47 and the resulting vector is still {2, 2}. This is somehow consistent with [this ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2271).

Comment: _The problem is, that even when vector_135.hpp is included, it makes no difference because the appropriate load method is not called_ - I am also not very keen on relying on a patch of some kind.

Comment: In Boost 1.48.0 vector_135.h, it explicitly states that 1.35 can't be compatible with 1.36-1.40. Perhaps this is a bug with 1.4.0 that isn't documented?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think your answer is nearly as complete as I hoped to get, but as it's the only one, I'll award you the bounty anyway. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @GeorgeSkoptsov: To be fair I have no idea about this particular problem, just some knowledge of Boost.Serialization and studied the code a bit to find this header.  If doesn't quite work, oh well... ;)